# Query related issue

Tags: oracle

I am unable to upload an image, but on my query the crime id repeats as there are two evidence types, is it possible to make it so it says Crime 1....... contains ..... Physical of which there are 1 and DNA of which there are 3?

The current result is:

> Crime 1 occured on 11/12/0013 and contains evidence type: Physical of
>   which there are 1.
>
> Crime 1 occured on 11/12/0013 and contains evidence type: DNA of which
>   there are 3.

The code is as follows:

```
  select 'Crime' || ' ' || crime.crime_id || ' ' || 'occured on' || ' ' ||
  crime.crime_date|| ' ' || ' and contains evidence type:' || ' ' ||
  evidence.evidence_type || ' ' || 'of which there are' || ' '|| 
  evidence.quantity || '.'  "Crime Data"
  from crime, evidence
  where crime.crime_id=evidence.crime_id
  order by crime.crime_id;
```

Comment: IMHO, using sql to construct human sentences is not a good idea, how do you process the query?

Answer (score 0):

We can use LISTAGG() to get quite close to this.

```
select  crime_str
        || evidence.evidence_agg_str
        || '.'  "Crime Data"
from ( select crime.crime_id
                , 'Crime' || ' ' || crime.crime_id || ' occured on ' ||
                    crime.crime_date|| ' and contains evidence type: ' as crime_str
         from crime ) crime, 
       (  select distinct crime_id
                 , listagg (evidence_str , ',') within group (order by evidence_type)
                   over (partition by crime_id) evidence_agg_str
         from (
               select crime_id
                              , evidence_type
                              , evidence_type || '  of which there are  '|| 
                                 quantity  as evidence_str
                 from evidence )
         ) evidence
  where crime.crime_id=evidence.crime_id
  order by crime.crime_id;
```

As you can see from [the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33209/10), the sentence structure is not perfect:

> Crime 1 occured on 12-NOV-13 and contains evidence type: DNA of which there are 3,Physical of which there are 1.

If this really matters to you, you can use REGEXP_COUNT to identify the last comma in the evidence string and REGEXP_REPLACE to substitute `and`.  It depends how complicated you want to get.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302).